# Adding a UILabel onto a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to draw a long string of text underneath the Title on a UINaviagtionController.

I tried adding a UILabel to by doing :

```
[appDelegate.NavControll.view addSubview:testLabel];
```

And the Label appears but doesn't animate/move with the navbar and just seems independent of it.

Is there a way to achieve this or should I leave it alone and come up with another idea for displaying this string somewhere else.

Many Thanks,
Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a label in your title bar and then on that label you can show your  title and your long string both.

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    // here's where you can customize the font size
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
    [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [titleLabel setText:@"hello\nhii"];
    [titleLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    [titleLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    [titleLabel setCenter:[self.navigationItem.titleView center]];
    [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleLabel];
    [titleLabel release];
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looks a little bit ugly, but it works [image]
You can easily customize appearance by yourself:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Needed title"; // for back button on pushed view

UIView *customTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
titleLabel.text = @"Title";
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(30, 10);
[titleLabel sizeToFit];
[customTitleView addSubview:titleLabel];
[titleLabel release];

UILabel *detailsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
detailsLabel.text = @"details";
detailsLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9];
detailsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[detailsLabel sizeToFit];
detailsLabel.center = CGPointMake(50, 35);
[customTitleView addSubview:detailsLabel];
[detailsLabel release];

self.navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView;
[customTitleView release];
```